# How to properly manage "business" constants with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, code-quality, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS on a browser game and I have a bunch of "business" constants.

These constants will be often updated during game testing (game balancing) and are used by different modules/features.

I'm currently managing them in a single file like that:

*constants.js*

```
var gameConstants =  {
    BASE_COST: 100,
    MULTIPLIER_COST: 1.07
};
```

*myFactory.js*

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function () {
    return {
         getRealCost: function() {
              return gameConstants.BASE_COST * gameConstants.MULTIPLIER_COST;
         }
    }
});
```

But I'm thinking about a service provider for game constants.
Something like:

*constantServices.js*

```
app.factory('ConstantServices', function () {
    var baseCost: 100,            //Should I use UPPER_SNAKECASE here too?
        multiplierCost: 1.07

    return {
         getCost: function() {
              return baseCost;
         }
         getMultiplierCost: function() {
              return multiplierCost;
         }
    }
});
```

*myFactory.js*

```
app.factory('MyFactory', ['ConstantServices' function (ConstantServices) {
    return {
         getRealCost: function() {
              return ConstantServices.getCost() * ConstantServices.getMultiplierCost();
         }
    }
});
```

What do you think about it? Is it a good idea to create a service provider for constants only (i. e. call a service without any logic)? Do you think about a better way to manage these constants?

Comment: If your game balance constants are stored in client side JavaScript, you should be prepared for people to discover and alter those values.

Comment: @DanPichelman You're right, it's intended. The game has to be full client-side.

Comment: edit: re-worded; I see no reason why you shouldn't encapsule the gameConstants object inside the 'ConstantServices' factory and just expose it's values via the public interface of the service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [constant service from AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant):

```
app.constant('gameConstants, [ 
  { BASE_COST: 100 },
  { MULTIPLIER_COST: 1.07 }
]);
```

And then inject the gameConstants wherever you need them:

```
app.factory('MyFactory', ['gameConstants', function (gameConstants) {
    return {
         getRealCost: function() {
              return gameConstants.BASE_COST * gameConstants.MULTIPLIER_COST;
         }
    }
}]);
```